# Como acessar, dentro de uma função, o membro de uma estrutura alocada dinamicamente?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, alocação, dinâmico

Tenho o seguinte código em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pessoa{
 char nome[11];
 int idade;
}
 
void cadastra_pessoa(char novo_nome[11], int nova_idade, struct pessoa *vetor_pessoas, int *quantidade)
{
  vetor_pessoa = realloc(vetor_pessoa, sizeof(struct pessoa) * (++(*quantidade)));
  strcpy(vetor_pessoa[(*quantidade) - 1].nome, novo_nome);
  vetor_pessoa[(*quantidade) - 1].idade = nova_idade;

int main()
{
 int quantidade_de_pessoas = 0;
 struct pessoa *vetor_pessoas = NULL;

 cadastra_pessoa("Robson", 12, vetor_pessoas, &quantidade_de_pessoas);
 cadastra_pessoa("Joao", 31, vetor_pessoas, &quantidade_de_pessoas);
 cadastra_pessoa("Ana", 19, vetor_pessoas, &quantidade_de_pessoas);
 return 0;
}
```

Cujo objetivo é aumentar dinamicamente o tamanho do vetor de pessoas (um ponteiro para struct) a cada vez que se cadastra uma pessoa. No entanto, o código dentro da função `cadastra_pessoa()`, que deveria aumentar o tamanho do vetor em 1 unidade a cada chamada e adicionar uma pessoa à ultima posição, simplesmente não funciona... a única parte que funciona é o incremento da variável apontada pelo ponteiro `quantidade`! Curiosamente, o mesmo código funciona totalmente quando é posto fora de uma função, diretamente dentro da `main()`. Por que somente dentro da função não funciona? Eu deveria, dentro da função, acessar os membros da struct de forma diferente ou essa tarefa não é possível de fazer através de funções?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está na variável do tipo ponteiro `vetor_pessoas` dentro de `main()`.
Mesmo depois da chamada da função `cadastra_pessoa()` o ponteiro `vetor_pessoas` continua apontando para `null`. Você deveria fazer esse ponteiro apontar para a nova região de memória alocada por `realloc` na função `cadastra_pessoa()`. Lembrando que você está passado o endereço apontado por `vetor_pessoas` para a função `cadastra_pessoa()`, e não o ponteiro em si.

Uma maneira de resolver esse problema é fazer a função `cadastra_pessoa()` retorna a nova região de memória alocada e atribuir a `vetor_pessoas`. Outra maneira seria a função `cadastra_pessoa()` receber um ponteiro para ponteiro.

Código abaixo testado no compilador MinGW-GCC versão 6.0.3, usando o primeiro método que descrevi acima

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include<string.h> //para uso da função strcpy

struct pessoa{
 char nome[11];
 int idade;
};
 
struct pessoa *  cadastra_pessoa(char novo_nome[11], int nova_idade, struct pessoa *vetor_pessoas, int *quantidade)
{
  vetor_pessoas = realloc(vetor_pessoas, sizeof(struct pessoa) * (++(*quantidade)));
  strcpy(vetor_pessoas[(*quantidade) - 1].nome, novo_nome);
  vetor_pessoas[(*quantidade) - 1].idade = nova_idade;
  return vetor_pessoas;
}

int main(){

 int quantidade_de_pessoas = 0;
 struct pessoa *vetor_pessoas = NULL;

 vetor_pessoas = cadastra_pessoa("Robson", 12, vetor_pessoas, &quantidade_de_pessoas);
 vetor_pessoas = cadastra_pessoa("Joao", 31, vetor_pessoas, &quantidade_de_pessoas);
 vetor_pessoas = cadastra_pessoa("Ana", 19, vetor_pessoas, &quantidade_de_pessoas);

 return 0;
}
```

Lembrando que o ponteiro `vetor_pessoas` é um ponteiro para uma região de memória continua com `structs` do tipo pessoa, logo essa região é um array, então para acessar o próximo elemento deve-se incrementar o ponteiro ou indexa-lo. Por exemplo:

```
... Mesmo código acima
printf(vetor_pessoas[1].nome) // ou printf((vetor_pessoas+1)->nome) para acessar o nome de João

return 0;
}
```